# Desktop icons and dock panel not showing

Tags: startup, plank, desktop-icons

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I recently encountered a problem that desktop icons and dock panel(I use Plank) not showing after my PC start-up. I found when this problem happens also night light doesn't work.
I can fix this by ending `Plank` process and opening it again so do desktop icons. This problem happens about 50%, is kind of annoying.
These two issues always happen together.